How to check if a csv row is empty in C#
I want to know how to check if a csv row is empty in a .csv file with c#, so that I can write data in it.
By an empty row I mean a blank row, with nothing inside it.
And also if you can help me figure how to write in the empty row, I would be helpfull
Here is the beginning of my function that uses a csv file and output the values
static public void ModuleSalarie()
    {
        string fileName = "Salarie.csv";
        string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Data\", fileName);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(reader))
            {
                parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                parser.SetDelimiters(",");

                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] ligne = parser.ReadFields();
                    foreach (string colonne in ligne)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(colonne);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

            }
        }
    }


What do you consider an "empty CSV row"? A blank line? A row where all values are empty strings?

What is parser? .Net has no built-in CSV parser, whatever you're asking about is a third party library.

I mean by an empty row a blank line, one of my row look like this:
1234567890123, Dupond, Jean, 1970-01-01, 123 Rue de la Paix, dupond@example.com, 0123456789, 2010-05-03, Directeur G�n�ral, 80000
I want to find the first row that is empty/null so that I can write other data in it

Can you add that to your question as a code block because it isn't possible to tell from the comment what the problem is

ok im doing it rn

you will need ro write the full csv again

Typically a CSV file is not used in a random access manner. Instead, you would read all the records in order and when you get to a blank one don't write it, but write out what you want to replace it with. As far as what constitutes a blank line: That depends on what ReadFields returns. I'm just guessing, but lingne.Length may be 0 or each item in ligne may have a length of 0.

@Blindy - .NET does have a built-in CSV parser: Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser.  The namespace mentions Visual Basic but it's perfectly usable in C#.  And that is in fact what the querent is using.  However, there is no corresponding built-in writer.

A valid CSV file cannot have an empty row (except may the last row). It must at least contain separators (e.g. ",,,,") and every line must contain the same number of separators.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes Actually, an empty row can be perfectly valid in a CSV file. If a CSV file contains a single column of data, and one of the values in that column is an empty string, it would be correctly represented as a completely empty line.

                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
                int pm = Array.IndexOf(lines, "");

                if (pm != -1)
                {
                    lines[pm] = "Your text";
                }
                else
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref lines, lines.Length + 1);
                    lines[lines.Length - 1] ="Your text";
                }
                File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
